# Why this simple C program uses has different cpu usage in Ubuntu and Windows?

Tags: c, cpu-usage

I'm new to programming and I've recently learnt if statement so I tried to wirte this program in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    int Value = 0;
    int Input = 100000000;
    ritorna:;
    Value++;
    if(Value < Input)
    {
        printf("%i\n", Value);
        goto ritorna;   
    }else
    {
        printf("%i\n", Input);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I wanted to see how it would behave in different machines in terms of speed, so i compiled it on my Ubuntu pc with a dual core cpu and then i did the same on a Windows machine with a way more powerful cpu. What i had is the code running at his maximum speed with 100%cpu usage on Ubuntu while on Windows it was only 50% usage (and so was slower).
I was wondering why this has happened...
Thanks

Comment: There is a lot that goes into this, but essentially each OS will have its own scheme (and default settings) for how it handles allocating processor time for any given program running in a mult-tasking environment. Additionally there are controls that assign priorities to various processes (and some of that is in the users control - see `man 1 nice` and `man 1 renice` on Ubuntu). It also depends on what else is running at the time, etc... What I've noticed over the years is windows defaults seem to reserve more CPU for windows, than Linux does for Linux. (those are adjustable settings too)

Comment: How many cores does your windows machine have?  Note that this program is single-threaded.

Comment: Unrelated: your `if ... goto ... else ...` loop could be written as `while (++Value < Input) { printf("%i\n", Value); } printf("%i\n", Input);`

Comment: the cpu on windows machine has 4 cores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things that can cause this.

First, programs that monitor CPU usage report in different ways. Windows Task Manager reports 50% for one entire CPU core at maximum use. Apple's reports 100% per CPU core, so a 8c/16t system reports 1600% usage for all cores at max.

Second, your program spends all of its time doing printf output. That depends on the speed of printf and the speed of the output console. On Windows that's pretty slow. Try speed comparisons while output is directed into a file.

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion, you are comparing not the cpu consumption of each program, as probably both will do the same things, but the differences between the I/O system in windows and in linux, as you print the values for each value of `Value`.

While `printf()` is optimized to do input/output in chuncks in both systems, the buffer sizes are optimized to get the best operating system performance, and in this sense, Windows and Linux are very different programs because they implement I/O in very different ways.  And think that looping for 100000000 iterations is a lot of input/output.

Answer (score 0):

I have a 4 core CPU on linux..   So the posted code only uses 25% of CPU.

Your windows machine has 2 cores, so the best that it can do is 50% of CPU.

in both cases, a whole CPU core is being consumed